# Matching ranges and specific patterns while keeping delimiter

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like to split a string apart by both a range and specific pattern while also keeping the delimter. From what I've found it's probably going to be best to use `match` instead of `split` Let's say I have the following code.

```
var stringy = 'a1 ... c3d4 ... f6';
var splitStringy = stringy.match(/[^0-9]+[0-9]+/g);
console.log(splitStringy);
```

Right now it returns:

```
["a1", " ... c3", " d4", " ... f6"]
```

But I'd like it to return (maintaining the spaces around the `...`):

```
["a1", " ... ", "c3", "d4", " ... ", "f6"]
```

Is there a simple way to modify my regex to keep it one line by matched the decimals with spaces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
s = 'a1 ... c3d4 ... f6';
m = s.match(/[a-z]+[0-9]+|\W+/g);
["a1", " ... ", "c3", "d4", " ... ", "f6"]
```

Comment: Thanks for making further edits, this one seems to be the golden one.

Comment: Sorry I had to adjust it few times but yes finally it came well.

Answer (score 0):

```
var splitStringy = stringy.match(/(\w+| \.\.\. )/g);
```

Will do it, which will match any word character (a-z, 0-9, underscore) sequences delimited specifically with ' ... '.

Results:

```
["a1", " ... ", "c3d4", " ... ", "f6"]
```

Comment: The only problem with this one is it doesn't break it apart after the numbers like my original example.

Comment: Oops, poor attention to detail on my part.

Answer (score 0):

The following would split everything out as you wish but won't retain spaces around the decimals:

```
var splitStringy = stringy.match(/[^0-9 ]+[0-9.]+/g);
```

That would return:

```
["a1", "...", "c3", "d4", "...", "f6"]
```

Comment: This one works too, though anubhava did keep the spaces around the decimals.